# Pass value from view to Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Lest say I got a view with this loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Blogposts)
{
  @item.Id
  @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("Date") 
}
```

So I got an Id and also a date choosen from the datePicker. Can someone show me how I can pass these two values to an Ajax that the loads a method?

```
$(".setDate").click(function () {


                    })
                    .load("/Home/Method?id=" + $(this).data("@itemID"));

            });
```

Am I on the right way with what i´ve done so far? Help appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the method to which I want to pass the values:

```
 public ActionResult SetDate(string valuefromDatePicker, string itemId)
        {

           //Code that updates the Time-property
            //This I can figure out

            return RedirectToAction("Test");
        }
```

Which should mean that the view should look something like this:

```
 @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("Date", new { data_url = Url.Action("SetDate", "Home", new { id = item.Id }) })
```

Should I also add a submit-button and give it the class .setDate?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using some custom `@Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker` extension method that is not part of ASP.NET MVC. You should have at least mentioned the custom library you are using. In general most of the jQuery UI helper methods have overloads with an `htmlAttributes` parameter. This would allow you to add custom `data-*` attributes that you could use in your javascript code later. Consult the documentation of the library you are using about how to specify custom HTML attributes but your code might look something along the lines of:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Blogposts)
{
    @item.Id
    @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("Date", new { data_url = Url.Action("Method", "Controller", new { id = item.Id }) })
}
```

and then in your javascript file:

```
$('.setDate').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $('#result').load(url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, 
This is the library im using:
http://jqueryuihelpers.apphb.com/Docmo/Datepicker

Please see update for the method i want to pass these values to.